# mean/plotting in R studio with imported data from excel

Tags: r

I imported a csv file from excel and I'm trying to find the mean and do a histogram plot.  The data set is N1.  I'm used mean(N1) and I get the following

```
N1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(13.56535447, 10.98573126, 9.819271544, 6.87414882, 8.303223126, 9.478439048)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
mean(N1)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(N1) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What am I doing wrong.  I the name and data is there because I can get the max and min but I can't get the mean or histogram plot.

Data example:

```
dput(head(N1))

N1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(13.56535447, 10.98573126, 9.819271544, 6.87414882, 8.303223126, 9.478439048)), 
.Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Right now we cannot know what is wrong with your data. I assume you imported the column names or anything not numeric within your data column(s), so R does not acknowledge the vector as numeric. Please provide a data example by pasting either the output of `dput(N1)` (if your data is small) or `dput(head(N1))` (if your data is large), so we can see what might be causing your error.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the average of all your dataset all a particular column? try this: `mean(N1$coloumn, na.rm = true)`

Comment: dput(head(N1))
structure(list(V1 = c(13.56535447, 10.98573126, 9.819271544, 
6.87414882, 8.303223126, 9.478439048)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `mean` on a `data.frame`, what you want is the mean of its only column. So `mean(N1$V1)` should solve your problem.